# Preload multiple months with FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have been working with FullCalendar for a while in my application and I now got to the stage of optimizing my application. One of the things I have been bothered by is the loading of new events when switching between months.

```
        ...
        },
        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
            var data = {
                'action'    : 'get_hours',
                'start'     : start.format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
                'end'       : end.format('DD-MM-YYYY')
            };

            $.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
                var res = JSON.parse(response);

                if (res.status) {
                    var events = [];

                    $.each(res.events, function(i, val) {
                        $.each(val, function(x, e) {
                            events.push({
                                title       : e.title,
                                start       : e.time_start,
                                end         : e.time_end,
                                allDay      : e.allday
                            });
                        });
                    });

                    callback(events);
                } else {
                    console.log(res.message);
                }
            });
        },
        ...
```

This function is called every time I switch months and triggers another AJAX request which causes my application to load. I want to get rid of this loading time. Ideally, I'd load the past 3 months, the current month and the upcoming 3 months.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Checkout this post https://code.google.com/archive/p/fullcalendar/issues/199

Comment: This is a different issue, namely displaying multiple months. I just want to load the data of multiple months through AJAX so I don't need to load every time I switch months. I don't need multiple calendars/views.

Comment: Initialize calendar inside callback of initial request for all those months. Store all the data and date ranges. Then check that before making new requests. Will also need to update  stored data objects though when you make changes to individual events within any view

Comment: this give you a small performance boost when moving between views / date ranges, but also slightly increase your up-front load time. Is it likely that your users will always try and view the 3 previous months and the 3 upcoming months? If that's very likely, then it might be best to pre-load the data. If it's relatively unlikely, then the current lazy-loading is actually a more efficient solution. Also read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/lazyFetching/ - the calendar doesn't fetch new events on _every_ change of view/date, it does try to be somewhat efficient already.

Comment: The other thing is, how long does your server take to reply with the updated events each time the ajax call runs? If it's more than a second or two, you ought to look at making your query more efficient. If it's less than a second or two, most users would find that acceptable, especially if you display some sort of "loading" indicator on the page to show what's happening. It takes a human brain a second or two to adjust to the change of display anyway, so it actually gives people thinking time.

Comment: @ADyson It is very likely for SOME users to look through all the months and they see it as an annoyance. Currently the loading takes maybe two seconds and a loading indicator is showing. The users were using iPhone's native calendar app before which switched instantly (obviously being a native app helps) so it is noticeable for them. The up-front load time is actually not a big deal since they can freely use the page without loading after. I've postponed adding the up-front loading for half a year now to see if they might get used to it, sadly it's still an annoyance.